# Several issues with a NSOpenPanel

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

What does these errors mean ?

[image]

This is my code:

```
[browsePanel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger returnCode)
{
    if (returnCode == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton)
    {
        if (returnCode == NSOKButton)
        {
            if ([sender tag] == 1) {
                // Templates
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[browsePanel directory] forKey:@"kPreferencesUserTemplateFolder"];
            } else if ([sender tag] == 2) {
                // Images
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[browsePanel directory] forKey:@"kPreferencesSaveImageFolder"];
            }
        }
        //FreeAndNil(browsePanel);
        if (browsePanel)
            [browsePanel release];
    }

}];
```

I also get a warning (I can't explain why):

```
"NSOpenPanel may not respond to '-beginWithCompletionHandler:'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Mac OS X Versions and Architectures are you targeting? `-beginWithCompletionHandler` is not available before 10.6

The `__Block_object_dispose` linker error is a little concerning because all libraries needed for blocks should be automatically linked in.

Comment: Blocks aren't available pre-10.6 either.